# X ray effects of high energy weapons

Tags: weapons, energy

**The question**

How much and what kind of power would such a weapon need to produce this effect if its possible at all?

**Additional info **

By x-ray effect, I mean when the projectile reaches the target, the x-rays will be so strong that you could temporarily see their skeleton

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. The human eye cannot see X-rays. So if any effect was caused by X-rays, a human being would not be able to see the skeleton.

The one range of frequencies where this could potentially work (so it could be seen by people) is in the visible light range, but there's a problem there--even in those areas where light could potentially pass through the human body, it diffuses and scatters. So what you end up with is light scattering and shining through the flesh, but too scattered to show where the bones are.

I know, it makes a neat visual effect--see the bad guy get zapped, and their skeleton shows through. It's been done in everything from cartoons to the movie *The Sum of All Fears*. But it doesn't actually work in real life.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible unless, you want to permanently see their skeleton... In that case, a particle accelerator would be fine.

Comment: If you want to permanently see their skeleton, baking the flesh off their bones would work too.  You know, if a particle accelerator isn't handy.